# How to increase vertical size of barplot with plotlys go.bar/ how to use same scale?

Tags: python, plotly

I created a subplot consisiting out of 4 barplots.

First, I want to increase the vertical size of each plot. I only find `row_heights`. With that I only can change single subplots.

Second, how do i employ that every subplots y-axis shares the same values? i.e. from 0 to 10k.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px

years = [1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,
         1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,
         2005,2006,2007, 2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,
         2018,2019]
tf_NB = [0,18,74,162,239,274,324,313,335,431,556,799,1018,1698,2386,2789,
         3071,2874,2633,2590,2118,2375,2741,3256,3211,3462,4440,3952,4233,3604,
         3812,4262,4894,5083,4529,4517,6279,7722,10310,6651]
tfidf_NB = [0,6,27,70,80,92,131,127,158,177,223,297,371,671,1005,1174,1389,
            1313,1259,1310,1031,1108,1294,1557,1415,1544,2039,1706,1860,
            1640,1702,1911,2160,2272,2065,2033,2853,3536,4700,3088]
tf_SVM=[1,14,37,71,110,136,188,165,213,219,285,299,440,693,951,1145,1289,
        1238,1132,1111,840,1032,1219,1458,1388,1381,1785,1526,1732,1519,
        1604,1808,2050,2116,1955,1995,2790,3507,4653,2950]
tfidf_SVM=[1,3,11,19,26,36,49,45,72,64,91,130,168,271,386,433,571,519,544,
           596,458,504,598,672,635,633,858,726,816,721,769,889,979,1008,924,
           902,1322,1657,2309,1488]

fig = make_subplots(rows=4, cols=1,shared_xaxes=True, horizontal_spacing = 1 , vertical_spacing = 0.1,
                        subplot_titles=("NB with TF", "NB with TFIDF","SVM with TF","SVM with TFIDF"))


fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=years, y=tf_NB),row=1,col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=years, y=tfidf_NB),row=2,col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=years, y=tf_SVM),row=3,col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=years, y=tfidf_SVM),row=4,col=1)
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the overall plot height, use

```
fig.update_layout(height = 1200)
```

To have all subplots use the same scale:

```
fig.update_yaxes(matches='y')
```